# Identifying start and end dates for medications with overlapping regimens

Tags: r, date

**What I have**

I have a dataset where I need to identify the `start and end dates` of a series of medications. A patient may start one medication, then stop it and start another one or even start the first medication again.

**What I need**

I need the start and end dates of each of these events. In some cases two drugs start at the same date and are administered concurrently (in these cases the drug names alternate by row but you can tell from the dates that they are administered at the same time period).

For this reason I'm unable to sort by drug name and then pull out the dates.

I would then like to be able to reshape the data into one row per patient with start and end dates for each round of medication.

I have included two example patients in the data structure below.

Data structure:

```
d <- structure(list(patient = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 

date.administered = c("25-Jan-00", 
"3-Feb-00", "10-Feb-00", "17-Feb-00", "24-Feb-00", "2-Mar-00", 
"9-Mar-00", "16-Mar-00", "23-Mar-00", "31-Mar-00", "1-May-00", 
"9-May-00", "16-May-00", "30-May-00", "11-Jul-00", "18-Jul-00", 
"25-Jul-00", "1-Aug-00", "8-Aug-00", "15-Aug-00", "22-Aug-00", 
"25-Sep-00", "25-Sep-00", "3-Oct-00", "3-Oct-00", "12-Oct-00", 
"12-Oct-00", "19-Oct-00", "22-Nov-00", "1-Dec-00", "8-Dec-00", 
"22-Dec-00", "28-Dec-00", "5-Jan-01", "19-Jan-01", "24-Jan-01", 
"26-Jan-01", "31-Jan-01", "2-Feb-01", "14-Feb-01", "15-Feb-01", 
"23-Feb-01", "28-Feb-01", "2-Mar-01", "16-Mar-01", "23-Mar-01", 
"30-Mar-01", "12-Apr-01", "19-Apr-01", "25-Apr-01", "30-Mar-00", 
"5-Apr-00", "14-Apr-00", "18-Apr-00", "28-Apr-00", "4-May-00", 
"11-May-00", "26-May-00", "1-Jun-00", "9-Jun-00", "23-Jun-00", 
"30-Jun-00", "10-Jul-00", "21-Jul-00", "27-Jul-00", "3-Aug-00", 
"18-Aug-00", "25-Aug-00", "1-Sep-00", "18-Sep-00", "22-Sep-00", 
"29-Sep-00", "17-Oct-00", "23-Oct-00", "30-Oct-00", "14-Nov-00", 
"20-Nov-00", "27-Nov-00", "12-Dec-00", "18-Dec-00", "22-Dec-00", 
"24-Jan-01", "29-Jan-01", "6-Feb-01", "20-Feb-01", "26-Feb-01", 
"5-Mar-01", "20-Mar-01", "26-Mar-01", "2-Apr-01", "24-Apr-01", 
"30-Apr-01", "7-May-01", "22-May-01", "28-May-01", "4-Jun-01", 
"26-Jun-01", "29-Jun-01", "9-Jul-01", "24-Jul-01", "30-Jul-01", 
"3-Aug-01", "21-Aug-01", "27-Aug-01", "5-Sep-01", "18-Sep-01", 
"24-Sep-01", "1-Oct-01", "30-Oct-01", "5-Nov-01", "9-Nov-01", 
"27-Nov-01", "3-Dec-01", "10-Dec-01", "22-Jan-02", "28-Jan-02", 
"4-Feb-02", "16-Apr-02", "22-Apr-02", "29-Apr-02", "14-May-02", 
"17-May-02", "27-May-02", "11-Jun-02", "17-Jun-02", "24-Jun-02", 
"9-Jul-02", "15-Jul-02", "22-Jul-02", "6-Aug-02", "12-Aug-02", 
"19-Aug-02", "3-Sep-02", "9-Sep-02", "16-Sep-02", "8-Oct-02", 
"11-Oct-02", "21-Oct-02", "5-Nov-02", "8-Nov-02", "18-Nov-02", 
"3-Dec-02", "9-Dec-02", "16-Dec-02", "7-Jan-03", "13-Jan-03", 
"20-Jan-03", "4-Feb-03", "10-Feb-03", "17-Feb-03", "4-Mar-03", 
"10-Mar-03", "17-Mar-03", "1-Apr-03", "7-Apr-03", "14-Apr-03", 
"29-Apr-03", "5-May-03", "12-May-03", "17-Jun-03", "24-Jun-03", 
"2-Jul-03", "22-Oct-03", "22-Oct-03", "29-Oct-03", "29-Oct-03", 
"5-Nov-03", "5-Nov-03", "19-Nov-03", "19-Nov-03", "26-Nov-03", 
"26-Nov-03", "3-Dec-03", "3-Dec-03", "14-Jan-04", "14-Jan-04", 
"21-Jan-04", "21-Jan-04", "28-Jan-04", "28-Jan-04"), 

medication = c("G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "F", "L", "F", "L", "F", "L", 
"M", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "D", "G", "D", "G", "D", 
"G", "G", "D", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "D", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "C", "F", "C", "F", "C", "F", "C", "F", 
"C", "F", "C", "F", "C", "F", "C", "F", "C", "F")), 

.Names = c("patient", 
"date.administered", "medication"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-180L))
```

Comment: I think you need to break this down to a *much* smaller example and then provide an expected output. E.g. 3 rows of 2 drugs for 2 patients, for about 12 rows total. Or at least give the expected result for this larger set, as it isn't clear what defines a start or a stop of any particular medication.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. First time posting so apologies if I haven't been clear. 

The start and stop of a medication is a little tricky to define but my best attempt is that it's the min and max date for the medication until a new medication is used. As mentioned in some cases two medications may be used together. So we would need the start and end dates for both of those medications.

I will attempt to make the dataset smaller as well as provide an expected output asap.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to break the problem into smaller chunk.

The first part is identifying the start and end dates of each medication.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

# Parse time stamp
d$parsed.date = as.Date(strptime(d$date.administered, format = "%d-%B-%y"))

# Get min and max dates per Patient per medication
d.filtered = d %>% 
  group_by(patient, medication) %>% 
  summarise(firstDate = min(parsed.date), lastDate = max(parsed.date)) %>% 
  ungroup()  %>% 
  mutate(firstDate = as.character(firstDate), lastDate = as.character(lastDate))
```

The second part is the reformatting of the dataframe. And `dcast` does the one line magic

```
# Reformat data frame 
firstDate = dcast(data = d.filtered, formula = patient ~ medication, value.var ="firstDate")
lastDate = dcast(data = d.filtered, formula = patient ~ medication, value.var ="lastDate")
```

Comment: Hi Dee, 
Thanks so much for your reply & for the scripts. It's very close to what I need. Where you've grouped the medications I need a little more detail from the data. I'd like to differentiate between the seperate courses of each medication per pt. E.g. In patient one, they actually have 2 courses of medication G (i.e. 25-Jan-00 to 22-Aug-00 and 22-Nov-00 to 19-Apri-01). Would it be possible to build some kind of changeable threshold (x) into the script to say that x > n (days) it will classify the medication as a second, third, fourth etc course of the medication. Open to all suggestions.

Comment: Actually this could be problematic as some patients may have longer medication cycles so the threshold might not apply to all patients. But it could be a good starting point?

Comment: In principle, you can define the logic in a function that takes in the dates and returns the date you desire. You can then use the code above, but instaed of using `min` and `max`, you can use   `summarise(firstDate=yourCustomFunction1(parsed.date), lastDate=yourCustomFunction2(parsed.date))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your Q correctly (would've been better to have a smaller example *along with the output you expect*), see if this helps:

```
require(data.table) 
setDT(d)[ , list(medication = medication[1L], 
                 start = date.administered[1L], 
                 end = date.administered[.N]), 
by = rleid(patient, medication)]
```

`rleid` is the key here. Understand what it does by looking at `?rleid`. Briefly, it gives the same number (id) to successive runs of identical values. We group by the ids created by `rleid` and extract the medication, start and end values. `.N` is a special symbol that corresponds to the total number of observations in each group.

PS: This assumes the `date.administered` column within each patient is already ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Aruns answer, in order to translate the rleid from the output dataframe back to the original ids from the input frame:

```
# this is what Arun does, the actual transformation
d2 <- d[ , list(medication = medication[1L], 
                 start = date.administered[1L], 
                 end = date.administered[.N]), 
by = rleid(patient, medication)]


# and then we add a group-identifier of the rleid to the old dataset
d[ , rleid := .GRP,
by = rleid(patient, medication)]

# and then we map those rleids to the ids to the output data
d2[, patient := plyr::mapvalues(rleid, from=d$rleid, to=d$patient)]
```